# HP Quality Center Web service

Tags: hp-quality-center

i'm trying to access the HPQC to get all the data into my database, aprt from IBM rational tool , is there any option available to achieve this, preferably .net

Answer (score 0):

You can use either REST or OTA API. Both of them has own advantages and disadvantages, in shortcut:

REST is more flexible in use, as you can use it wherever you want, but it's functionality is limitted (f.e. DesignSteps are not supported)

OTA API is based on COM library, it's much more "powerfull" an thanks to this can be used f.e. in Excel. The problem is, that you can't use it outside Windows.

More info you can find on help page in QC ALM under API REference